# DOS Downloaders / Downloads Managers (e.g. WGET) any more?

Tags: windows, command-line

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [wget/cURL alternative native to Windows?](https://superuser.com/questions/299754/wget-curl-alternative-native-to-windows)

I am currently looknig for a DOS down-loader similar to wget, are there any alternatives for Windows?

Comment: DOS and Windows are two *different* operating systems. In addition, DOS hasn't been used for the last 15 years or so. (Well, in some sense Windows 9x operating systems are DOS applications.) The command line interpreter `cmd.exe` that is found in Windows has nothing to do with the old DOS operating system! So, are you looking for a DOS application or a command-line (console) Windows application?

Comment: If you're looking for Windows command line (excellent point @Andreas), [cURL](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html) may work for you.  Look for the binary download not the source.

Comment: @jonsca Thanks, actually I just found it myself :)

Comment: Please see this link http://users.ugent.be/~bpuype/wget/ , you can download the same wget exe and can be run on dos same as linux,... To retrieve with passwords (http or ftp), you can use the following url syntax:

wget http://username:password@www.example.net/somedir/somefile
wget ftp://username:password@ftp.example.net/somedir/somefile

Answer (score 7):

Wait, [what](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/wget.htm)?

Comment: I've used this wget version for years: http://users.ugent.be/~bpuype/wget/

Comment: +1, you don't need a wget *alternative*.

Answer (score 1):

However, if you would like an alternative, [aria2](http://aria2.sourceforge.net/) is very nice.  Handles HTTP/S, FTP, Metalinks, BitTorrent, segmented downloads, preallocation, download resuming, reading cookies from Firefox/Chrome, can be daemonized and controlled via JSON-RPC/XML-RPC.

A GUI frontend is available in [uGet](http://urlget.sourceforge.net/).